# I know folder name and filename. How to find the subfolder name using cmd

Tags: command-line

I have a file name `a.txt`. I know directory name is `d:\karthick` but i don't know the subdirectory name using cmd prompt.

Example: `d:\karthick\sabari\a.txt`

I dont know know sabari folder. Using cmd prompt i need to find.

Answer (score 1):

try this on the command line:

```
dir /s d:\karthick\a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

type the folowing at command prompt, you should get a list with subdirectories and files in the directory(three commands):

```
D:

cd karthick

dir
```

to open the file with default viewer, then you can type:

```
D:\karthick\"subdirectory"\a.txt
```

Comment: or `dir /ad` to list only directories. If you know the file name try `dir /s a.txt`